# How to display a text in SVG1.1 from bottom to top using text element?

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to display a text in Vertical manner from bottom to top way. I am using text element to render the text in SVG1.1.

One way is to use transform and rotate the text is there any better way to do that because I even tried doing writing-mode: tb or bt but in case of tb it is rendering properly from top to bottom but in case of bt it is not doing the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bottom-to-top text rendering in [SVG 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#SettingInlineProgressionDirection) or in [CSS3 Writing Modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/), a reason why is cited in the [abstract of CSS3 Writing modes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/#abstract).

As you suggested already the way to do this right now is with transforms. You may also use the [glyph-orientation-* properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#GlyphOrientation) or the [`rotate` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#TextElementRotateAttribute).

Note that I'm not sure how well the glyph-orientation properties are supported across browsers at this stage, and they're essentially being deprecated in CSS3 writing modes (replaced by new keywords/properties).